# Prevent click on certain elements

Tags: javascript

I'm working on portfolio items, where every item looks like this

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-title"></div>
    <div class="item-subtitle"></div>
    <div class="item-image"></div>
    <div class="item-site"></div>
</div>
```

Previous div is hidden and items are shown by this code

```
<a class="project" :href="`http://www.${item.site}`"  >
```

So, if I put like "mysite.com" in item-site div and hover over item output is www.mysite.com and that is ok if item-site is not empty. But if that div is empty output is www. and I dont want that.Is there a way to prevent that?
How to dissable click if item-site class is empty, so if I click on it nothing happens, but if is not empty and has link then if I click it's opens that link in new window.

Comment: If you click on any of these elements, "nothing" is exactly what happens already.  Presumably you have code somewhere which is responding to those click events.  That's the code you need to look for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pointer-events: none` CSS statement to disable the hover and click events on an element.

In your case, it might look something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-title"></div>
    <div class="item-subtitle"></div>
    <div class="item-image"></div>
    <div class="item-site not-clickable"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.not-clickable{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

If the DOM element (in this case `<div class="item-site"></div>`) is empty, then add the class `not-clickable`. If the element has content, then remove the class `not-clickable`.

Please also note that `<div>` tags are not clickable by default. It sounds like you want these to be links which are `<a>` tags. Also, an `<a>` tag without the `href` attribute has no pointer events - so an alternative would be to provide the `href` when you want the element to be clickable, and remove it when you want the element to not be clickable.

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-title"></div>
    <div class="item-subtitle"></div>
    <div class="item-image"></div>
    <a class="item-site">I should not be clickable</a>
    <a class="item-site" href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">
      I should be clickable, and I will also open in a new tab
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is a pen that might explain further:
https://codepen.io/mikeabeln_nwea/pen/yZQLaj?editors=1111